# Как скрыть Toolbar при открытии navigation drawer?

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar, android-navigation-drawer, android-style

Здравствуйте, как поместить Navigation Drawer под Toolbar? чтоб когда я слева вытягиваю это самое меню, - toolbar не вылазил наперёд

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

метод onCreate из главного активити:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Для Activity с боковым меню ставьте эту тему,
    // для Activity без бокового меню ставьте тему AppThemeNonDrawer (она прописана по умолчанию в манифесте кстати)
    // иначе будет "сползать" ActionBar
    // Темы находятся в styles.xml
    setTheme(R.style.AppThemeDrawer);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // init Drawer & Toolbar
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    headerResult = Utils.getAccountHeader(MainActivity.this, savedInstanceState);
    drawerResult = Utils.createCommonDrawer(MainActivity.this, toolbar, headerResult);
    drawerResult.setSelectionByIdentifier(1, false); // Set proper selection

    // Покажем drawer автоматически при запуске
    drawerResult.openDrawer();

}
```

**AndroidManifest:**

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher2"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name=".HeadspaceApplication">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

**styles.xml :**

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
</style>

<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="AppThemeDrawer" parent="MaterialDrawerTheme.Light.DarkToolbar.TranslucentStatus">
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
<item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/window_background</item>
<item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppThemeNonDrawer" parent="MaterialDrawerTheme.Light.DarkToolbar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/window_background</item>
</style>

<style name="AppThemeStation" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus" tools:targetApi="kitkat">true</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
</style>

<style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored"/>
<style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.Button.Colored" />

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/holo_blue_dark</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/rt_green</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/tc_orange</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
<style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.Button.Borderless" />
<style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base" />

<style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

удалось спустить целиком navigation drawer под toolbar, задав программно **.withDisplayBelowToolbar(true)** в методе **createCommonDrawer(...)**
но как же всё таки сделать его просто поверх, а не опускать вниз??

Comment: вместо манифеста и стилей больше пригодилась бы разметка этого экрана

Answer (score 0):

.withDisplayBelowToolbar(true) - показвает под тулбаром